# STL & Overloading in C++

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading

I've created a doubly-linked list out of nodes. I'm working with the STL. I'm getting an error in the `operator++` function. Here's my `Iterator<T>` class.

```
#include "Node.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T> class Iterator{
public:
    Iterator();
    ~Iterator();
    Node<T> *node;
    void operator++(Iterator<T> val);
    void operator--();
    T operator*();
private:

};

template<class T>
Iterator<T>::Iterator(){
    node = 0;
}

template<class T>
Iterator<T>::~Iterator(){

}

template<class T>
void Iterator<T>::operator++(Iterator<T> val){
    if(node != 0){
        node = node->next;
    }
}

template<class T>
void Iterator<T>::operator--(){
    if(node != 0)
        node = node->prev;
}

template<class T>
T Iterator<T>::operator*(){
    if(node == 0){
        cout << "Node no exists!";
    }

    else{
        return node->value;
    }
}
```

I'm also getting a warning in my `main` function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    List<int> mylist;

    for(int i = 2; i < 10; i++){
        mylist.push_back(i);
    }

    Iterator<int> it = mylist.begin();

    while(it.node->next != 0){
        cout << it.node->value << "\n";
        it++;
    }


    mylist.pop_front();
    cout << mylist.front() << ", ";
    cout << mylist.back();
    return 0;

}
```

> **ERRORS AND WARNINGS**
>
> F:\New folder\C++\Lab14\Iterator.h||In instantiation of 'class
>   Iterator':|
>
> F:\New folder\C++\Lab14\main.cpp|15|required from here|
>
> F:\New folder\C++\Lab14\Iterator.h|29|error: postfix 'void
>   Iterator::operator++ (Iterator) [with T = int]' must take 'int'
>   as its argument|
>
> F:\New folder\C++\Lab14\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
>
> F:\New folder\C++\Lab14\main.cpp|19|error: no 'operator++(int)'
>   declared for postfix '++' [-fpermissive]|

By the way, I'm planing to do the same with the other operators too. The `operator*` is not for multiplication.

Comment: Man, learn to format your code...

Comment: `error: postfix 'void Iterator::operator++ (Iterator) [with T = int]' must take 'int' as its argument`  - which part of the error message you don't understand?

Comment: What does it mean that you are "working with the STL"?

Comment: @jalf that could mean that he's using the Standard Library's definition and requirements for an iterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`operator++` must either take a single `int` or no argument:

```
void operator++(int);
void operator++();
```

The first is the overload for postfix `++` and the second for prefix `++`. The `int` argument is only to allow the correct overload to occur; its value is unspecified.

Your declaration of `operator++` currently looks like this:

```
void operator++(Iterator<T> val);
```

It seems like you're expecting the object that is being incremented to be passed as an argument. Actually, the object is the object pointed to by `this`. You would implement your `operator++` like so:

```
template<class T>
Iterator<T> Iterator<T>::operator++(int) {
    Iterator<T> copy = *this;
    if(node != 0) {
        node = node->next;
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Note that I've also returned a copy of the object before changing its `node` member. This is usually expected of a postfix increment operator.

To get prefix increment, overload with no argument. It should return `*this` by reference. ie.
    Iterator operator++(int); // postfix
    Iterator & operator++(); // prefix

Answer (score 3):

Like most operators, there are two ways you can define `operator++`. You can write it as a member of the iterator class, or as a free function. But there's another complication, because there are two forms of `operator++`: prefix and postfix. So writing that operator takes a bit more thought.

As a member:

```
struct Iterator {
    Iterator& operator++();   // prefix
    Iterator operator++(int); // postfix
};
```

As a free function:

```
struct Iterator { };
Iterator& operator++(Iterator&);     // prefix
Iterator operator++(Iterator&, int); // postfix
```

Answer (score 0):

`operator++` shouldn't take an argument. Removing the argument from both the prototype and definition should fix your error.

And just as a little '*pointer*' (get it?), the dereference operator probably should return a `node<T>`, not `T`. (You can do both, but the former makes more sense, and would make it behave in a similar way to `std` containers.)